# Question using cylindrical coordinates to find center of mass

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, physics, multiple-integral, cylindrical-coordinates

I was just wondering if someone could please help me check my work/answer for this problem:

Let $W$ be the ice cream cone region bounded above by the hemisphere $z=\sqrt{2-x^2-y^2}$ and below by the cone $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and with mass density $\delta(x,y,z)=z$

a) Find the mass of $W$.

b) Find the $z$-coordinate of the center of mass of $W$.

Work for part a):
\begin{align} 
M &= \iiint_{D}\delta \, dV \\ 
&= \int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{2}} 
    z r\, dz\,dr\,d\theta \\
&= \int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{1} r\,dr\,d\theta \\
&= \int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{1}{2} d\theta \\ 
&= \pi
\end{align}

Work for part b):
\begin{align} 
M_{xy} &= \iiint_{d} z\delta\, dV \\
&= \int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{2}} 
    z^2 r \,dz\,dr\,d\theta \\
&= \int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{2\sqrt{2}}{3} r \,dr\,d\theta \\
&= \frac{2\sqrt{2}}{3} \int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{1}{2} \,d\theta \\
&= \frac{2\sqrt{2}}{3}\pi 
\end{align}

$$
\bar{z} = \frac{M_{xy}}{M} 
= \frac{2\sqrt{2}}{3}\pi \cdot \frac{1}{\pi} 
= \frac{2\sqrt{2}}{3}.
$$

Comment: Your integral for the mass $M$ has $0 \leq z \leq \sqrt{2}$, so the region is a solid cylinder. You want $r \leq z \leq \sqrt{2-r^2}$ instead.

Comment: @SammyBlack So when I change it to the correct bounds I get $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{1} \frac{r(2-r^2)\sqrt{2-r^2}-r^4}{3} dr d\theta$ does this seem correct to you? Because this question was on a previous one hour exam so solving this integral would take a really long time. just wondering if I'm missing something?

Comment: The innermost integration looks like 
$$
\int_r^{\sqrt{2-r^2}} \! zr \, dz = \biggl. \frac12 z^2r \biggr|_r^{\sqrt{2-r^2}} = \frac12 \biggl( (2-r^2)r - r^2r \biggr) = r - r^3
$$

Answer (score 3):

No, that is not correct. As you know, $\theta$ can take any value in $[0,2\pi]$. For each $\theta$, $r$ can take any value in $[0,1]$. But the range of the possible values of $z$ is $\left[r,\sqrt{2-r^2}\right]$. So, for instance, the mass is equal to$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1\int_r^{\sqrt{2-r^2}}zr\,\mathrm dz\,\mathrm dr\,\mathrm d\theta=\frac\pi2.$$

Comment: oh wow, but then doesn't that make $M_{xy}$ a pretty complicated integral? After integrating with respect to z I get $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{1} \frac{r(2-r^2)\sqrt{2-r^2}-r^4}{3} drd\theta$ and this is a pretty complicated integral right?

Comment: Not really:\begin{align}2\pi\int_0^1\int_r^{\sqrt{2-r^2}}z^2r\,\mathrm dz\,\mathrm dr\,\mathrm d\theta&=\frac{2\pi}3\int_0^1-r^4+r(2-r^2)^{3/2}\,\mathrm dr\\&=\left[-\frac{r^5}5-\frac15(2-r^2)^{5/2}\right]_{r=0}^{r=1}\\&=\frac{2\pi}3\left(-\frac25+\frac{4\sqrt2}5\right).\end{align}